# Can't boot Ubuntu after installation

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot

I just installed Ubuntu on my laptop which currently has Windows 7 installed on it as well. Somehow when I first rebooted my laptop after installation, it seemed like it failed to boot. After that there appears an option to choose between Ubuntu or Windows 7. When I choose Ubuntu, it goes back to the first screen which shows the same fail. I forgot what it said.

Could someone please help me?

I'm still new to Ubuntu and interested in using it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with your MBR, GRUB installation, or something of the sorts - try running Ubuntu using live media so you can download and run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Simply put, you can type this in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

You can then launch the utility via the Dash or with the command `boot-repair`. Follow the recommended instructions and I believe it should at the very least do a full reinstall of GRUB2. You may be able to perform these same steps using the root prompt in the recovery tool (second boot option).
Otherwise, it could be an issue with the installation itself, for which you could try to run the diagnostic utilities provided by the recovery tool, or you may have to reinstall.